# spring boot app - beanUtils not found

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, maven

In eclipse I create a new spring boot starter project. The Spring Boot Version is `1.5.9.RELEASE` and the dependency I include is the `spring-boot-starter-web` (this is all done by the Spring Project wizard in eclipse, so likely no error there). When I run it as Spring Boot app, I get the error

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot instantiate interface org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextInitializer : org.springframework.boot.context.ConfigurationWarningsApplicationContextInitializer
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:413)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:392)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:383)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.initialize(SpringApplication.java:249)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.<init>(SpringApplication.java:225)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107)
    at spring.demo.rest.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:10)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/beans/BeanUtils
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:409)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 8 more
```

The class [BeanUtils](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/BeanUtils.html) is in the spring-beans library which is clearly imported

[image: spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar in maven dependencies]

[image]

This is my pom

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>spring.demo.rest</groupId>
<artifactId>restdemo</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>demo</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Note: I am behind a corporate proxy and the nexus we have mirrors the maven central repo. I have setup the proxy in settings.xml

**EDIT**

What I noticed was that the `spring-beans4.3.13.RELEASE.jar` is installed to `org/springframeword/spring-beans/4.3.13.RELEASE` but the app looks for `BeanUtils` in `org/springframework/beans/BeanUtils`. There must be some version incompatability right?

Comment: Have you tried running it from the command line using Maven? Or only Eclipse? `org/springframeword/spring-beans` is that a typo? `org/springframework/spring-beans/4.3.13.RELEASE` is the folder, but `org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils` is the package. Unlikely to be a version incompatibility, since the parent is managing the versions. Can you open the jar file here as a ZIP: `org/springframework/spring-beans/4.3.13.RELEASE`, is it a valid jar? Pressing ctrl+shift+t and typing BeanUtils an Eclipse shows the class?